# Linking an image to an external url

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to link an image to an external URL from my index.html.erb page but it's not working. Any suggestions?

```
<%= link_to image_tag "facebook.png",  "http://www.facebook.com"  %>
```

I am also trying to link a 'send-to-friend' email image - so when a user clicks it, their email client will open automatically with a pre-written title and message ready to send. Can anyone help with this one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It may be thinking the url is a second parameter to the `image_tag` method rather than to the `link_to` method, so wrap that up the `image_tag` parameters in parentheses to avoid confusion:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("facebook.png"), "http://www.facebook.com" %>
```

Comment: That is spot on. Any ideas on how to implement a 'send to friend' function from an email image as above?